# Orphaning: calling glBufferData with a NULL pointer, really?

Tags: opengl

From OpenGL wiki:

> If you will be updating a small section, use glBufferSubData. If you will update the entire VBO, use glBufferData (this information reportedly comes from a nVidia document). However, another approach reputed to work well when updating an entire buffer is to call glBufferData with a NULL pointer, and then glBufferSubData with the new contents. The NULL pointer to glBufferData lets the driver know you don't care about the previous contents so it's free to substitute a totally different buffer, and that helps the driver pipeline uploads more efficiently.

I realize from my research, what they mean by "helps pipeline upload more efficiently" is it allows asynchronous buffer writes which makes dynamic buffers faster.

However, this excerpt and others seem to suggest that the "NULL" argument to the glBufferData is very important, and it's the cause for the orphaning and it's what promotes asynchronous writes.

But my common sense is telling me, it doesn't need to be null, you can put a pointer to some of your data there instead of null. The important part for the orphaning is just the fact that you're calling glBufferData again and therefore reallocating the storage of the buffer, therefore orphaning the old storage, therefore allowing asynchronous writes. Am I correct by thinking this?

Comment: When you call glBufferData, the driver is allowed to reuse the same storage (unless the size is not big enough etc.). The NULL pointer is really a special case where the driver is sure you don't want him to reuse the storage. In my experience, doing this never really helped, so maybe you are right and the driver does it anyway. But there is no way to be sure.

Comment: @Jerem but NULL is suppose to indicate the data of your storage to be undefined. How does it also indicate that the storage be different than the old storage? I don't see this written in the glBufferData doc. And if this is really the case, that is subtle, arbitrary, and ugly API characteristic.

Comment: Yeah you're right it's kind of arbitrary. I don't know how exactly how this came to exist but it's been there a long time.

Comment: When the driver get the NULL, it knows/predicates you are going to use "Buffer Orphaning", and it will allocate a new VRAM for you, and you can glMap* the new VRAM out for cpu usage as soon as you want, but no need to wait the old VRAM which may be using by GPU. If you use 'non-Null', then glBufferData will re-upload these data to GPU and that cost time to copy between cpu and gpu, you can't call glMap* at once in next line.